# How to redirect traffic on basis of user agent using AWS S3 - Cloudfront setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, web-hosting

I am using Nginx reverse proxy to redirect my traffic from mobile device to one docker container and desktop to another docker container. Attached is the nginx conf file I am using.
So the user who opens `something.xyz` from mobile is shown separate frontend and who opens from desktop is shown separate frontend.

Now for obvious reasons I want to host both mobile as well as desktop frontend in S3-Cloudfront. I am clueless as how can I segregate mobile traffic and desktop traffic and redirect them to separate s3-cloudfront.

```
events {
    worker_connections 4096; ## Default: 1024
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name something.xyz;

        if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod|Opera Mini|Android.*Mobile|NetFront|PSP|BlackBerry|Windows Phone)') {
            set $ua_type "@mobile";
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

            if ($ua_type = "@mobile") {
                proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:82";
            }
            if ($ua_type != "@mobile") {
                proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:81";
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What nginx has to do with CloudFront? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Hi @Marcin This is existing nginx conf i am using in an ec2 instances where I am hosting two reactJs applications in docker container. Now I want to do away with ec2-docker-nginx setup and use cloudfront. This conf is nothing but shows existing setup.

Comment: usually the redirections on CF are obtained using lambda@edge as exemplified [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-redirect-to-signin-page). CF functions (newer techonology) could also be used.

Comment: @Marcin But do we have a way to do the said redirection which wont result in changed url?